# Fast join on Multiple IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

Whith `s_records, q_records, d_records, i_records` all of type  `IEnumerable<MyRecord>`, `querytwo` works just as expected. But what if I want to join multiple `IEnumerable` on the same equality of the same fields?

```
        var querytwo = from a in s_records
                       join b in q_records
                       on a.date equals b.date
                       select new { s_line = a.line, q_line = b.line };

        Console.WriteLine(querytwo.Count());
```

This `query` doesn't work I am trying to do the same as in `querytwo`, but join on multiple `IEnumerable<MyRecord>`:

```
        var query = from a in s_records
                    join b in q_records                       
                    join c in d_records
                    join d in i_records
                    on a.date equals b.date equals c.date equals d.date
                       select new { s_line = a.line, q_line = b.line, d_line = c.line, i_line = d.line };
```

Comment: I think it should be `join b in q_records on a.date equals b.date join c in d_records on b.date equals c.date...`. There are some similar questions on SO with similar titles which give correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is to off to some extent. it should be:

```
var querytwo = from a in s_records             
               join b in q_records on a.date equals b.date 
               join c in d_records on b.date equals c.date
               join d in i_records on c.date equals  d.date
               select new { 
                   s_line = a.line, 
                   q_line = b.line, 
                   d_line = c.line,
                   i_line = d.line 
               };
```